# Checking for the surrounding cells in an arraylist

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel, grid-layout

Basically I'm developing a little game which consists of the user connecting 9 cells of the same colour, it is not restricted by lines as long as the cells are connected by the surrounding cells.

The problem is that I don't know how to check for all these possibilities to confirm a winner.Somehow I need to check the arraylist for all these possible outcomes.

This is an image which could be useful to specify what I'm trying to achieve.

```
    for (Cell cell : grid.getCells()) {
        if (cell.getBackground() == checkColor) {
            for (Cell cell2 : grid.getCells()) {
                if(cell2.getBackground() == checkColor && cell2.getx() == cell.getx()
                        && cell2.gety() == cell.gety() + 1) {
                    win++;
                    System.out.println("Right " + win);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This manages the left and right verification. Works well but I can't figure out why is this checking for both left and right , I thought it would only check right but it seems to work both ways

Comment: I already done something ... But it is check left and right so, it checks left and right which adds another won to the winning variable which is not working fine. I edited the post with some code.

Comment: What is the question exactly: How to calculate all possible winning combinations? Or verifying if the combinations chosen by players are valid?

Comment: Verifying that the combinations are valid !

Comment: I did the left and right code for now

Comment: I think it would be more efficient to store your cells in a 2D array (or nested array list), instead of a simple 1D `ArrayList`. Then, starting from a given point in the array, at given coordinates, it would be very easy to check surrounding cells.

Comment: if two adjacent cells are connected with same color ,your code will increase variable win by 1. so i cant understand what did you mean by right or left, because when two cells are connected one relative to a one cell the other cell might be in left or right